# Blog categories not rendering properly in drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, categories

I'm a Rails beginner trying to allow users to assign a single category to their postings. The categories list is handled in a separate table.

The drop down works in that it shows two options when there are two categories and three options when I add a third. The problem is it isn't showing the category names, but what seem to be system identifiers of some kind.

Specifically here is a screen grab:

[image]

This is the relevant code:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.select :category, Category.all, :prompt => "Select One" %>
</div>
```

And the schema

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "category_name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objects**

The problem you have is basically that when you load a series of `ActiveRecord` objects (with the likes of `Category.all`), they are just going to come back with a series of objects that
your application can use.

As you've demonstrated by your image, your `select` box is only outputting the [`Ruby` object](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_classes.htm) - which means that you will need to output a specific *attribute* of the object in order to make it work the way you wish.

--

To do this, as `SteveTurczyn` has pointed out, you should tell Rails which attributes to use as the `:value` and `outputted text` of the element:

```
<%= f.select (:category_id, Category.all, :id, :category_name) %>
```

---

**DB Structure**

Something you should consider is the structure of your database - if you've got a data table called `categories`, you'll generally want to keep the `attribute` names single words which can *add* to this name.

Essentially, your `category_name` should just be `name`, as this will allow you to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
Class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @category = Category.find params[:id]
        #-> @category.name
        #-> your current = @category.category_name
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the recommended format...

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :category_name, :prompt => 'Select One') %>
```

The `:id` indicates which attribute is to be inserted into the `:category_id` form field, and the `:category_name` indicates which attribute is to be displayed for the selector.